# How to develop Stacked Column Chart

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, charts

I want to create Stacked Column Chart using ASP.NET, C#.

Can you give me examples to develop stacked column bar chart. And the series values are shown in bar, count at the top side of the bar. I am new to develop chart in dotnet.

Can anyone suggest me, how can I achieve this.

Would appreciate url's where can I find the demo to do this completely.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131991/microsoft-chart-stacked-column-chart-has-gaps)  may help you also [see for more info](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/)

Or
[see this](http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart,%20adding%20data%20manually&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 1):

you may use following code
First add chart in aspx page as following:

```
  <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="500px">
                            <Series>
                                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="StackedBar"></asp:Series>
                            </Series>
                            <Series>
                                <asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartType="StackedBar"></asp:Series>
                            </Series>
                            <ChartAreas>
                                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                            </ChartAreas>
                        </asp:Chart>
```

Then write following code:

```
 using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select MonthName,TotalTruck,Item from table1", cnn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Chart1.DataSource = dt;
            Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "MonthName";
            Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "TotalTruck";
            Chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "Item";
            Chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "TotalTruck";
            Chart1.DataBind();
           }
        }
```

It will stack Item in the bars.