# chart1.DataBindCrossTable return unpredictible results

Tags: c#, charts

below is the code I use:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connstring = "%my connection string%";
        string query = @"%my query%";
        OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(connstring);
        oc.Open();

        OracleCommand ocom = new OracleCommand(query, oc);
        OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();
        p1.Value = dtp1.Value.Date;
        ocom.Parameters.Add(p1);
        OracleParameter p2 = new OracleParameter();
        p2.Value = dtp2.Value.Date;
        ocom.Parameters.Add(p2);

        try
        {
            dt.Load(ocom.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        //*********
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        this.chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dt.Rows, "PROGRAM_NAME", "STARTDATE", "MINUTES", "");
        foreach (Series ser in chart1.Series)
        {
            ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        }
```

it generates pretty good chart and I am generally satisfied form results until ... it is a short period of time. When I choose wider time interval my column has empty holes. Below two screenshots: 
The first one shows only 5 days of March. 9th of March column reach value of 200 (minutes)
[image: 7-11 of march][image]

and the second 
shows 15 days of March . 9th of March should also be 200 but it finish just below 200 and then there is a hole before the last blue bar
[image: 7-11 of march] [image]

Do  you have any idea why such a failure appears ?

Data from 9 of march

[image]

są the first chart is correct , the second one , with hole has a failure.

Comment: Show data in your `DataTable` and your `Legend`.

Comment: Some xvalues are missing points in some series. you need to synch them!

Comment: @jstreet Legend and data from 9th of march added.

Comment: @TaW What do you mean "synch xvalues" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'holes' actually are misplaced bars and many should go to one or more points to the left..!  See here:

[image]

The DataPoints must be 'synch'ed' or 'aligned'. This means each `Series` of `ChartType` `StackedXXX` **must** have a `DataPoint` at **each** of the X-Values of **any** other Series .

There is a long [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744549/stacked-column-chart-in-c-sharp/35745456#35745456) that should explain it all..

Note especially the link to [this interesting chart function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints
```

has several overloads to help aligning stacked charts.